# jQuery Remove Attribute Does Not Work

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I have div like this on my page:

```
<div style="padding-top:10px;" id="message2">
    <p>More Links: <span class="fa fa-plus add"></span></p>
    <div class="appending_div">
        <div class="blog_links">
            <p class="blog_linku_1">
                Link URL 1: <input type="text" name="blog_linku_1[]"> &nbsp; Link Name 1:  <input type="text" name="blog_linkn_1[]">
            </p>
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

So simply if user click on **+** sign, it will add another input field just like this one with this script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var i = 2;
    $('.add').on('click', function() {
        var field = '<p class="link'+i+'">Link URL '+i+': <input type="text" name="blog_linku_'+i+'[]"> &nbsp; Link Name '+i+':  <input type="text" name="blog_linkn_'+i+'[]">&nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus minus" id="minus'+i+'"></span></p>';
        $('.appending_div').append(field);
        i = i+1;
    })
    $('#minus'+i+'').click(function(){
        $(".link"+i+"").remove();
    }); 
})
```

And if you mention out, the extra links contains a remove symbol which is a **-** sign, and by clicking this sign, the paragraph which has the class `link"+i+"` should be removed.

And now the problem is that the remove icon does not work when you click on it. And the Console bar does not show any error message.

So what is your idea about this, how can I solve this problem?

Comment: You need to add an [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example so we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've restructured your code a bit. See below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var i = 2;
    $('.add').on('click', function() {
        $('<p class="link' + i + '">Link URL ' + i + ': <input type="text" name="blog_linku_[]" /> &nbsp; Link Name' + i + ':  <input type="text" name="blog_linkn_[]"> &nbsp; <span class="fa fa-minus minus"></span></p>')
            .appendTo('.appending_div');
        i = i + 1;
    });
    
    $('.appending_div').on('click.remove', '.minus', function () {
        $(this).parent()
            .remove();
    });
})
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="padding-top:10px;" id="message2">
    <p>More Links: <span class="fa fa-plus add"></span></p>
    <div class="appending_div">
        <div class="blog_links">
            <p class="blog_linku_1">
                Link URL 1: <input type="text" name="blog_linku_1[]"> &nbsp; Link Name 1:  <input type="text" name="blog_linkn_1[]">
            </p>
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

I've simplified the top portion of your code that adds the element to the screen. Since you are using *jQuery* you can combine a few of these steps with the chaining of their library functions.

For the event handling, because the elements are added dynamically, you need to delegate the events to the new elements. Recall that elements must be present on the page for the event to be bound. Otherwise, the events must be delegated to an existing element. *jQuery* will handle the abstractions and the *"bubbling"* of the events to the parent element.

Comment: Using fields names as array `[]` and `index` is illogical... also your answer generates invalid HTML code.

Comment: @War10ck I really appreciate your answer. But if you run the code on your answer, and click on **+** to add some more link inputs, and then remove some of them with **-** sign, and after that, again click on **+** sign, it will add links from the last point that link were added. Just try it and you will see what I mean!

Comment: @War10ck So do you know any way to fix this? Therefore, if someone adds link, it will start from number 2 again. Not any other number.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki Sorry about that. I removed the excess `indexes` and `ids`. I also fixed the malformed HTML.

Comment: Good @War10ck, but that makes your answer almost a copy of mine :p

Answer (score 1):

First, it will be better to attach the event to a common class instead of using incremented values

Example :

```
var i = 2;
$('.add').on('click', function() {
    var field = '<p class="link">Link URL ' + i + ': <input type="text" name="blog_linku[]"> &nbsp; Link Name ' + i + ':  <input type="text" name="blog_linkn[]">&nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus minus">----</span></p>';

    $('.appending_div').append(field);

    i++;
});
```

**NOTE: Since you're using input names as array `[]` you don't have to generate them with indexes.**

You need to use the event delegation **[.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** when you attach the click event to `.minus` since the elements are generated dynamically :

```
$('body').on('click','.minus', function() {
    $(this).closest('p').remove();
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var i = 2;
  $('.add').on('click', function() {
    var field = '<p class="link">Link URL ' + i + ': <input type="text" name="blog_linku[]"> &nbsp; Link Name ' + i + ':  <input type="text" name="blog_linkn[]">&nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus minus">DELETE</span></p>';
    $('.appending_div').append(field);
    i++;
  });

  $('body').on('click', '.minus', function() {
    $(this).closest('p').remove();
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div style="padding-top:10px;" id="message2">
  <p>More Links: <span class="fa fa-plus add"></span></p>
  <div class="appending_div">
    <div class="blog_links">
      <p class="blog_linku_1">
        Link URL 1: <input type="text" name="blog_linku_1[]"> &nbsp; Link Name 1: <input type="text" name="blog_linkn_1[]">
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<button class="add" type="button">Add</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the `#minus` element on `$(".add")` *click*, so when the DOM loads it cannot find the `$("#minus")`. You have to add the `$("#minus")` *click* function inside the `$(".add")` *click*.

Try the below code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var i = 2;
    $('.add').on('click', function() {
        var field = '<p class="link'+i+'">Link URL '+i+': <input type="text" name="blog_linku_'+i+'[]"> &nbsp; Link Name '+i+':  <input type="text" name="blog_linkn_'+i+'[]">&nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus minus" id="minus'+i+'"></span></p>';
        $('.appending_div').append(field);
        i = i+1;
        $('#minus'+i+'').click(function(){
            $(".link"+i+"").remove();
        });
    });
});
```